# Flutter - How to Invoke a Function of one page from another page

Tags: flutter, state-management

I have 3 pages - HomePage, FirstPage, SecondPage. HomePage contains a futureBuilder which will fetch data from Server and display it in the HomePage. From HomePage I can navigate to FirstPage (using Navigator.push()) and from there to SecondPage. In the SecondPage I am sending some new data to server. A progress indicator will be shown while sending the data. Now if I press back button two times I will reach the HomePage back. But now the data in HomePage is the same as before. i.e, The data is not updated in the HomePage even if the data is updated in the server. I have button in HomePage which onTap will call setState() and then the Data will be Updated.
But I want the data of HomePage to be updated just after the data is sent from the second page. i.e, from second page we will first show a progress indicator, then we will send data to server, then we will update the data of home page in some way, then only we will stop the progress indicator.So if then we tap back button and return to HomePage, Home page should show the updated data. I don't want to call setState() after clicking back button to home page because it will cause to show a progress indicator(a delay in fetching updated data) again.

Is there any method to do this? Or is there any way to call the setState() method of HomePage from the secondPage ?

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. Fetch data from Server using global variable. After send the data to server use `ChangeNotifier()`
function. (Notes: learn about provider package)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a BehaviorSubject from https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart Using a BehaviorSubject, you can wrap your HomePage in a StreamBuilder that 'watches' the data that you know will be updated. You can call an add to the BehaviorSubject object to keep it up to date everywhere in your build. I personally put it in a Singleton if I want that state to sit across many pages. Another option is to elevate it until it is the 'grandparent' of any page that will use it and then it can be exposed by passing it down, a singleton or otherwise.